# How to fetch details of all installed apps in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, sandbox

is there any way  by using code  to get details like appsize,installed date,packaged name of all apps installed in our iPhone ?
i have searched a lot but i haven't been able to get an accurate answer

p.s-i have seen apps in appstore like this ,so it must be somehow possible

http://peepapp.net/

http://itunes.apple.com/in/app/zwapp/id426360184?mt=8

Answer (score 3):

No you can't. You can not access other application's info from your app.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot discover info about or even existence of other apps on a device... don't you think that would violate app sandboxing principles?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible from within an app. However, you can request this information if you're using MDM and the device has been appropriately enrolled.